# File uploading in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I try to make a simple letters storage:

Letter.php:

```
class Letter extends DataObject 
{
  private static $db = array (
    'DateUpload' => 'Date',
    'LetterNumber' => 'Text',
    'Theme' => 'Text',
    'Sender' => 'Text',
    'SendTo' => 'Text'  
  );

  private static $has_many = array (
    'LetterFiles' => 'LetterFiles'
  );

  public function getCMSFields(){
    $fields = FieldList::create (
      TextField::create('Theme','Theme'),
      DropdownField::create('Sender','Sender'),
      ...
      $uploader = UploadField::create('FileName','Attached Files')
    )
    ...
  }
}
```

LetterFiles.php:

```
class LetterFiles extends File 
{
  private static $has_one = array (
    'LetterOfFile' => 'Letter'
  );
}
```

LetterAdmin.php:

```
class LetterAdmin extends ModelAdmin 
{
  private static $managed_models = array (
    'Letter'
  );
  private static $menu_title = 'Letters';
  private static $url_segment = 'letters';
}
```

But when creating a new letter in the admin interface I can't attach a file: I can upload it, but after pressing the button "Save" I can not see it in the "Attached Files" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UploadField` should use the relation you have on your `DataObject`. In your case, that would be `'LetterFiles'`:

```
$uploader = UploadField::create('LetterFiles', 'Attached Files')
```

Another minor thing: I strongly suggest you don't use `File` subclasses for custom file-relations. It'll only work when you upload files directly, if you upload a file somewhere else in the CMS (eg. the assets-admin) and want to link them using the "Choose existing" dialog, then it'll fail.

I suggest you just delete the `LetterFiles` class and use a `many_many` relation on your `DataObject`. Example:

```
// Change from this…
private static $has_many = array (
    'LetterFiles' => 'LetterFiles'
);

// … to this:
private static $many_many = array (
    'LetterFiles' => 'File'
);
```

Comment: Thank you bumzak! It's helped me.